# Reference to iterator in for loop in c++

Tags: c++, stl

In this code, *k* is always 0. Where as *val* points to the next element. Both are initialized within the for loop, one changes its value but the other does not.

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::find
#include <vector>       // std::vector

int main() 
{


std::vector<int> myvector = { 0,1,2,3,4 };


// iterator to vector element:
for (auto it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end(); ++it)
{
    int k = 0;
    int& val = *it;
    int& j = k;
    std::cout << j << " : " << val << std::endl;
    ++k;
}


return 0;
}
```

In vs2013 this prints:

```
0 : 0
0 : 1
0 : 2
0 : 3
0 : 4
```

Edit:

Answer is

The } at the end of the for-loop-body destroys all the variables inside of it. Then ++it increments the iterator, and then it re-enters the body, and recreates the variables.  val is initialized to the new value each time it's created.

Comment: What is your question?  What did you expect to happen?

Comment: the question was "How come K is always 0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a variable inside the scoop of the for loop a new instance is created for every iteration and deleted at the end of the loop. Your `int k = 0;` creates a new variable of type integer for each iteration over the loop. The `int& val = *it;` statement creates a variable the references the same memory address as `*it`. The `int& j=k;` statement creates a reference to the value held by k. At the end of the loop `++k` increments the value of `k` to one just before deleting the variable.

Programming in C++ and C it is important to understand when a variable is created and where it will be deleted. You also need to understand the relation between a variable and its memory address, that is where the value of a variable is stored.

As a side note, neither of the statements `int& vale = *it` and `int& j =k` serves any purpose and the optimiser will discard them. As the rules of C++ dictates that the value of `k` is always zero it is also likely that the optimiser will discard that variable and replace the print statement with

```
std::cout << 0 << " : " << *it << std::endl;
```

Comment: In more complicated cases, I prefer taking references `myclass& val= *itr` so as to avoid using `it->` every time. The initialization question answered this.

Comment: @Chanakya, and my preference would be to write `itr->whatEver()` but that is not the important point. What I hoped to explain is that introducing the reference, as is your preference, will not incur any overhead.

Answer (score 3):

`k` is initialized with the constant value zero, whereas `val` is initiated to whatever `it` references at that iteration of the loop!

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy, this is because you have created `k` inside the loop. Move the creation outside the loop:

```
int k = 0;
for (auto it = myvector.begin(); it != myvector.end(); ++it)
{
```

as for `val` you are assigning it to `*it` which as shown in your loop increments every time (`++it`).
If you want to assign it to the beginning then you can do this:

```
 int &val = *myvector.begin();
```

Although, i am not sure what you hope to achieve with this.

Comment: why is *val* pointing to newly incremented *it*. *val* should be initialized just once..

Comment: @Chanakya: The `}` at the end of the for-loop-body destroys all the variables inside of it.  Then `++it` increments the iterator, and then it re-enters the body, and recreates the variables.  `val` is initialized to the new value each time it's created.

Comment: @Chanakya: `val` _is_ initialized just once. But you have _n_ different versions of `val`...

Comment: Said it better than i could have.